# Web application

Tags: web-applications

its my first web application in real world and am very much confuse from the beginning
am working on Merchandise suppliers application, which includes various type of products.

for an instance Home > products> cloths > men > t-shirts > add basket >send information to my client,
I don’t need to add PayPal  , just need to send information to my client ,

So far I have done , analysis , site structure , page designing am confuse about database designing(I want to add customers detail, Product Detail, Order detail ), am using VB.net and SQL server

Can any one help me out or send me some example step by step how should I begin with it .

Comment: You could begin by giving some details such as: what programming language and database are you using; what data you want to store in the DB etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article on database design:
http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html

Start with the key objects (Possibly Products & Users in your case), and expand out from there.

Always review your database design with someone else before you start using it, even if it's someone who isn't technical. What you want to be able to do is identify where ALL the data is stored, and how the data relates to other areas.

You can do this by working through your web pages, and checking if you have added the necessary fields to your database.

Answer (score 0):

- [web coding learning reference](http://www.w3schools.com)
- [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
- [W3School's SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Start there for Database information and basic use of SQL / integration with web projects. After that I would suggest picking up a book on database structure and doing some real research.